# ASP.NET Core - Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime?' and 'int'

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-5 Web API I have this code:

```
public class DashboardCountDto
{
    public int? AllMandateCount { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentYearMandateCount { get; set; }
}

public List<DashboardCountDto> GetDashboardFieldCount()
{
    DashboardCountDto data = new DashboardCountDto();
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    data.CurrentYearMandateCount = _context.zib_mandates.Where(m => m.CreatedDate == current.Year).Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().Count();

    List<DashboardCountDto> dataCount = new List<DashboardCountDto>();
    dataCount.Add(data);

    return dataCount;
}
```

CreatedDate is DateTime datatype

This is to return the count of records for the current year.

I got this error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime?' and 'int'

How do I get this corrected?

Thanks

Comment: try `int?` to `int`?

Comment: How about `m.CreatedDate?.Year == current.Year`?

Comment: @juunas that won't work, as the left hand can be null. You need a null check and then m.cd.Value.Year.

Comment: Works for me in LinqPad. The question mark is the null check.

Comment: @juunas And what if it's null?

Comment: The condition will be false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try it:

```
public List<DashboardCountDto> GetDashboardFieldCount()
    {
        DashboardCountDto data = new DashboardCountDto();
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime currentYear=   DateTime.Parse($"{current.Year}/01/01");
        data.CurrentYearMandateCount = _context.zib_mandates.Where(m => m.CreatedDate >= currentYear).Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().Count();

        List<DashboardCountDto> dataCount = new List<DashboardCountDto>();
        dataCount.Add(data);

        return dataCount;
    }
```

Comment: That's not the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your line you write

```
data.CurrentYearMandateCount = _context.zib_mandates.Where(m => m.CreatedDate == current.Year).Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().Count();
```

*But **CreatedDate is Date Type and current.Year is int type**. so If you compare with year you should write*

```
data.CurrentYearMandateCount = _context.zib_mandates.Where(m => m.CreatedDate.Year == current.Year).Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().Count();
```

Hopefully it works

Comment: Nope. It's not `DateTime` but `DateTime?`. So it's nullable.